# Why does the AWS console UI still reference a key pair I have deleted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

If I click the "Connect" button for my EC2 instance, step #2 references a private key for a key pair that no longer exists.

```
2) Locate your private key file (something.pem).
```

But the associated key pair does not exist, because I deleted it in AWS console.  Is this just a UI problem in AWS console, or am I misunderstanding something about how keys are managed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commands in the "Connect" UI refer to the name of the key pair specified during the launch of the instance.  The name matches the key pair name that you see in the "Description" tab of the instance.  This can't be changed.  Even if you delete the key pair in AWS console, the instance you launched is still associated with that key pair.

In my case, an ISP problem resulted in a temporary change to my IP address, and thus my new IP address no longer matched the one in my security groups.  In my initial effort to debug, I took a variety of things that may have resulted in my private key no longer working, so that when I corrected the IP address in my security groups, I was still locked out.  (I then went ahead and deleted the key pair, but still saw it referenced in the AWS UI as explained in my question.)

Fortunately, mine is an EBS-backed Linux instance, so I was able to recover, like so:

1. Create an AMI of my instance.
2. Create a new instance based on my AMI. This saved me from having to rebuild my entire server and re-deploy my application.  When you create the new instance based on the AMI of your old instance, this is your change to associate a new key with the instance.  The AWS UI makes this clear enough.
3. Dissociate my Elastic IP from the old instance.
4. Associate my Elastic IP with the new instance.

I then had one remaining problem affecting SSH access, which others might not run into:  the RSA key in my local known_hosts file was now bad.  When I tried to SSH into AWS, I saw an error in my terminal that referenced the specific line in my known_hosts that was the problem.  This was the important part of the error message:

```
Offending RSA Key in /some/path/to/known_hosts:3
```

That number at the end tells you what line in known_hosts is the problem, and in my case I just deleted that line and then was able to SSH into AWS again, and my new instance worked the same as the old one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are talking about this, but if you have deleted your private key, you can't access your instance.

> Amazon EC2 doesn't keep a copy of your private key; therefore, if you
>   lose a private key, there is no way to recover it. If you lose the
>   private key for an instance store-backed instance, you can't access
>   the instance; you should terminate the instance and launch another
>   instance using a new key pair. If you lose the private key for an
>   EBS-backed Linux instance, you can regain access to your instance. For
>   more information, see Connecting to Your Linux Instance if You Lose
>   Your Private Key.

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html](http://UserGuide)

Comment: Close.  I didn’t delete my private key, but did delete the key pair in AWS console.  I went ahead and answered the question once I had a resolution.  Thanks.